# How do I set up Undertale on an iPad?

Tags: ios, undertale

My nephew is all excited about Undertale, but did not play the game yet. I would like to gift it to him for Christmas. Unfortunately, he only plays games with his iPad (and is not computer savvy) and I am only familiar with Windows and Linux.

Is there an 'official' way to play Undertale on an iPad? What is the best (simplest for me and easiest to use for him) way for me to set this up? Where can I find detailed and easy-to-use instructions to make this work?

I set up an account on Steam and noticed that it's possible to give games to another user. It would be no problem to set up another account for him and give the game from my account to his, but I don't know if this will work with his iPad.

Comment: Would you be open to Steam Link and streaming from a PC to an iPad?

Comment: I don't know what that means, but will look into it. Where can I learn how to do it?

Comment: Ouf, that looks complicated! If my nephew can use Steam link, then he can just use a computer. Thanks though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you but I don't think something like that is possible on an iPad.

From what I know you can't easily port something from a PC to something like an iPad unofficially. You could either hope for the developer to develop and release a port to iPad someday or since your nephew isn't that computer savvy there's still an official Nintendo Switch port of Undertale that exists.

Hopefully this answer can help you.

Comment: Thanks (and awww...). I know that there is an official OSX version of Undertale out there. Would that work on an iPad (with iOS, I guess)? If 'yes', how?

Comment: Well yes, there may be an official OSX version out there but that doesn't mean it's available on the iPad. Running things on an Apple computer and running something on an Apple device like an iPad are totally different things.

Comment: @StevenMathey Unfortunately that wouldn't work. OSX is what Macs use, IOS is what Ipads use. They are 2 completely separate operating systems.

Comment: Steve did your nephew got to play Undertale already? Otherwise I'm sure they will be very happy to also get a Nintendo Switch to play it :)

Answer (score -1):

Play a fake version of undertale on iPad. You can find in on App Store it is called,(There is no escape from love) actually! That’s what the game is called. I play it a lot and I think it is a really good way to play undertale on an ipad